# Python when substituting "**" instead of "+" into Fibonacci

Tags: python, fibonacci

My code, stuck at 6561, unable to continue. I have tried printing B, I've tried substituting while True for a counter of greater value than the amount being printed. I have also tried different numbers for the original values, this could sometimes make it worse; eg. "a, b = 9, 10" will only print 9 and 10. Question, how do I unstick it?

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alOOt.png)

UPDATE: It appears that if you run this code in idle, then create a new python file, python stops responding.

Comment: That's fascinating. Do you have a question?

Comment: Code and question now in the original part. Sorry for inconvenience, I thought both were there.

Comment: You do realise this will be generating huge numbers? It's trying to print a lot of digits, which I would guess is what is making it crash. The sequence is 2, 3, 8, 6561, 8^6561 (this has nearly 6000 digits).

Comment: Ah, however python can handle this number outside of the code with ease.

Comment: If I multiply instead, then the code will go on for a long time, I had it once taking 20 minutes to load a single number before I got bored and closed it. It isn't a problem with loading the numbers, it's a problem with the code, possibly in a bug in the True loop.

Comment: Please don't use an external image to show code. This can easily be pasted into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug with the code, it's a direct consequence of the size of the generated numbers.

`8 ** 6561` is a 5926 digit number. The next step in the sequence is 6561 raised to the power of that *5926* number. That's where it gets stuck - the computation is simply too large for Python to handle in a reasonable amount of time.

Python supports arbitrary sized integers beyond the native size supported by the hardware, and the implementation requires memory to store the digits of the integer. The result is that your program will consume more and more memory until either the answer is produced, your system/process runs out of memory, or you run out of patience.

You will find that it works with multiplication and addition simply because the numbers involved are smaller, and so it will take a lot longer to reach the huge sizes produced by exponentiation.